# ¿Tenemos algún equivalente a "six pack" en castellano?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

Hace un tiempo leí en The Workplace [este comentario](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/55220/can-a-boss-tell-an-employee-not-to-go-to-human-resources#comment141935_55228)

> Very good answer. (...) My teacher, instead of being pissed and angry
>   at him, **went to see him with a six-pack and suggested they talk to
>   each other**. The guy apparently had a very crappy life but this was
>   enough for him never to park on my teacher's spot again. To this day,
>   they still talk. Sometimes the nice way is clearly the best way.

Aparte de lo interante de lo que dice en sí, me quedé pensando en si tenemos en castellano algún equivalente al "six-pack" inglés. Es decir, alguna forma de referirnos a un paquete de seis bebidas, normalmente cervezas.

Pienso y pienso y no se me ocurre nada. ¿A alguien le suena algo?

Comment: En Venezuela se le llaman los chocolaticos

Comment: Recuerdo un episodio de la serie Blossom en el que su amiga Six explicaba por qué se llamaba así: "Mi padre se tuvo que beber seis cervezas para animarse cuando me concibieron". Obviamente, en inglés decía "six-pack", pero me temo que en español no tenemos un equivalente extendido.

Comment: No pasa nada si no hay una palabra especifica para eso. A veces ocurre. Si yo tuviera que traducir esa frase diría "fue a verle con unas latas de cerveza". Se pierde la información de que eran seis, pero se explicita el hecho sobreentendido de que eran cervezas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acuerdo a este foro de discusión en [WordReference.com](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/six-pack.2038079/?hl=es), las expresiones mas comunes son:

- Paquete de seis
- Six Pack

Parece que ambas expresiones son comprensibles cuando se trata de cervezas (especialmente, cervezas *en lata*); hay otras expresiones que derivan de las expresiones anteriores según cada país.

Un término también empleado para pedir un paquete de cervezas es:

- *Petaco de cervezas* o simplemente *petaco* : Sin embargo, este *paquete* incluye mas de seis cervezas (24 unidades exactamente).

Para extender la respuesta, La expresión *six-pack* también se entiende para referirse a los abdominales; para este caso en específico, he escuchado el siguiente término:

- *Chocolatina*: Debido a la similitud de las divisiones que tienen las barras de chocolate.

Por otra parte, en las siguientes líneas se puede leer:

> *¡Todos tienen **lavadero** y yo tengo **lavadora**!* [fuente.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tsr4K4H2yhI)

He escuchado (aunque en menor medida que *chocolatina*):

- Lavadero: Esto es por lo firme/sólido de la superficie donde se lava y restriega la ropa.

Comment: ¡Cierto lo de la chocolatina! A lo que muchos añaden "mejor un barril de chocolate que una simple chocolatina" ;-)

Comment: En relación a los paquetes de cerveza, yo sólo he escuchado (en Argentina) "paquete de seis" o "six-pack", pero este último únicamente en lenguaje publicitario, porque suena más _cool_. En cuanto a los abdominales, también es más común _tabla de lavar_ (y las barras pequeñas de chocolate son _chocolatines_ en Argentina).

Comment: En México decimos *plancha* al paquete de 24 y simplemente *six* al de seis, pero publicitado como *six pack*.

Answer (score 1):

Existe el término "gavera" (lo puedes buscar en dle.rae.es) que generalmente es para 24 bebidas. Cuando son seis, he escuchado decir "una gaverita de seis".

Comment: Lo bueno del stack es que todos los días se aprende, Este es un nuevo término para mi. Según la RAE es usado en Venezuela cuando a bebidas se refiere. En Colombia nunca lo he escuchado.

Answer (score 0):

Hace algunos decenios era más acostumbrado en España referirse a cantidades por docenas.  De hecho, los huevos se siguen vendiendo por docenas.
Los *"packs"* de seis unidades se suelen llamar **medias docenas** que, además, es fácilmente comprensible por toda la comunidad hispanohablante.